# Remove case insensitive duplicates in sql (postgres)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization, case-insensitive

I have a postgresql database, and I'm trying to delete (or even just get the ids) of the older of the duplicates I have in my table, but only those who are because of case sensitivity, for example `helLo` and `hello`.

The table is quite large and my nested query takes a really long time, I wonder if there is a better, more efficient way to do my query in one go, and not split it up to multiple queries, cause there's a lot of ids in question

```
SELECT * FROM some_table AS out
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM some_table AS in
    WHERE out.text != in.text 
    AND LOWER(in.text) = LOWER(out.text) 
    AND in.created_at > out.created_at) > 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
SELECT LOWER(text), ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION by LOWER(text) ORDER by created_at ) as rn
FROM some_table
```

You can then use the `rn` column as a filter

Comment: A good solution that worked for me!
Though for people copying it or using it in the future, the comma after `PARTITION by LOWER(text)` is not needed and should be removed

Answer (score 0):

To help this query, create an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on `LOWER(text)`. Include `created_at` in the index to help the date comparisons.

```sql
CREATE INDEX text_lower ON some_table(LOWER(text), created_at);
```

It's hard to test this without your data, though.